# contentDetails don't exist in some responses of Activities with YouTube Data API v3

Tags: api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have a problem on using YouTube API.
I requested as follows:

```
http://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/activities?part=contentDetails&channelId={CHANNEL_ID}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Then I received the response:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#activityListResponse",
 ....
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#activity",
   "etag": etag1,
   "id": id1,
  },
  ....
```

There is no property of contentDetails although I specified it. It exists in the next activity.

```
  ....
  {
   "kind": "youtube#activity",
   "etag": etag2,
   "id": id2,
   "contentDetails":{
    "upload":{
     "videoID": videoed
    }
   }
  },
  ....
```

What does it depend on whether contentDetails exist? In fact the first activity is "bulletin" whereas the second one is "upload". Do this concern?

Comment: Show me the documentation that says contentDetails contains "comment", "likes".. I think your referring to ["Youtube Metrics"](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/v1/reports/metrics)

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected response of `contentDetails`- it only returns the `videoId`. You can see that in [Activities resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities#resource)

```
"contentDetails": {
    "upload": {
      "videoId": string
    }
```

You can even try this in  [Google API Explorer Activities.list](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.activities.list), be sure to tick "all" in "use fields editor".

If you want a more detailed response, use `snippet`:

```
 "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": datetime,
    "channelId": string,
    "title": string,
    "description": string,
    "thumbnails": {
      (key): {
        "url": string,
        "width": unsigned integer,
        "height": unsigned integer
      }
    },
    "channelTitle": string,
    "type": string,
    "groupId": string
  }
```

Comment: "contentDetails" contains "like", "favorite", "comment", "subscription", "playlistItem", "recommendation", "bulletin" and "social" not only "upload".